# VDS Ubuntu подключение второго сервера

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, hdd, vds, ssd

помогите найти ответ, могу ли я на созданном виртуальном сервере, подключиться ко второму виртуальному серверу/или своему пк. Так, чтобы я мог использовать их ssd/hdd на первом виртуальном сервере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это возможно.

Идея в следующем:

1. Создаём VPN подключение ко второму серверу. В качестве VPN можно выбирать OpenVPN, L2TP или PPTP. Если у Вас нет большого опыта с VPN - советую начать с PPTP, его конфигурация самая простая. [Вот](https://alexell.ru/blog/ubuntu/vpn-pptp-server-na-ubuntu.html) очень неплохая инструкция по настройке. Правда, я бы, вместо того, чтобы возиться с iptables, просто вырубил бы файервол. Если захочется использовать L2TP - можно попробовать использовать готовый докер-образ, это сильно уменьшает работупо конфигурированию.
2. Когда у Вас есть VPN  - это то же самое, что локальная сеть! Можно поднять любой сетевой проттокол для шаринга дисков - NFS или CIFS. Мне больше нравится CIFS - он виндовс - совместимый и очень производительный.

Конечно, это всё - не очень просто, но разобраться можно. Советую потренироваться на домашней сети, а когда всё будет получаться - повторить конфигурацию на хостинге.

И последнее. Если Вы захотите использовать локальный диск домашнего ПК на хостинге - у Вас может возникнуть проблема с тем, что нет "белого IP", и вообще - нет возможности установить соединение со стороны сервера. Тогда придётся использовать то, что называется reverse ssh - то есть, создать соединение со стороны домашнего компьютера, и уже по нему гнать весь остальной трафик.

Answer (score 1):

раз в метках упомянут протокол ssh, то в наличии **уже** имеются и туннель, и, как его следствие — виртуальная частная сеть. т.е., нет надобности в установке и настройке **дополнительных** реализаций туннелей/сетей.

монтируем каталог с удалённой машины к себе локально:

```
$ sshfs пользователь@машина:/каталог/там /каталог/здесь
```

обратная задача: монтируем локальный каталог на удалённую машину с помощью [rsshfs](https://github.com/rom1v/rsshfs):

```
$ rsshfs /каталог/здесь пользователь@машина:/каталог/там
```